# Form Events with the same Entity in Symfony (nested sets)

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms, symfony

I'm using the nested tree set from **stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle** in Symfony 3 to create category hierarchy. I'm trying to create a **dinamic generation of submitted forms**, so when I choose a category it shows me the subcategories.

I have tried the example from the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-submitted-data) and it works fine when I use different entities, for example retrieve a city when you choose a province, both in different entities.

But when I do it in the same entity (using nested sets), I'm always getting the error: **Entities passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe persist them in the entity manager?**

I have tried two ways to get the children, with choices:

```
$formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Category $category = null) {

    $children = null === $category ? array() : $category->getChildren();

    $form->add('children', EntityType::class, array(
        'class'       => 'AppBundle:Category',
        'placeholder' => '',
        'em' => 'ManagerRegistry',
        'choices' => $children
    ));
};
```

And with the query_builder:

```
$formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Category $category = null) {

    $form->add('children', EntityType::class, array(
        'class'       => 'AppBundle:Category',
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use($category) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                ->where('c.parent = :category')
                ->setParameter('category', $category);
        }
    ));
};
```

But I get the same error (well EntityType uses ChoiceType so I guess they produce the same 'choices').

My Category entity is the default one from the doctrine extensions bundle, the code is the same from the documentation, and it works fine with different entities.

How could I get the children categories?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's a [bug](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/13964) and there is a [pull request](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/17694) to fix it.

My solution is to inject an entity manager and use ChoiceTypes:

```
class SearchSubType extends AbstractType
{
protected $em;

public function __construct(ObjectManager $em)
{
    $this->em = $em;
}

public function getCategories()
{
    $categories = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')->getRootNodes();
    return $categories;
}

public function getChildren(Category $category)
{
    return $children = $category->getChildren();
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('category', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'choices' => $this->getCategories(),
            'choice_label' => function ($value, $key, $index){
                return $value;
            }
        ));

    $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, $data = null) {

        if($data === null) {
            $data = new Category;
        }

        $children = null === $data->getCategory() ? array() : $this->getChildren($data->getCategory());

        $form->add('subcategory', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'choices' => $children,
            'choice_label' => function ($value, $key, $index){
                return $value;
            }
        ));
    };

    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            $data = $event->getData();

            $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data);
        }
    );

    $builder->get('category')->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {

            $category = $event->getForm()->getData();

            $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $category);
        }
    );
}
```

}